# Installing Hadoop in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java, hadoop

I am pretty new to Ubuntu/linux and totally new to Hadoop.

I'm following the guide here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04

I an using Java 9.0.1 and am trying to install Hadoop 2.8.2.

It's a very nice guide, but I seem to have hit a snag.

To give some background I did not complete the checksum check in part 2 because the mds link for the version of Hadoop I downloaded appears to be dead.

Also prior to finding the guide above I had a couple of aborted attempts to install java and setting the environmental variables for java! I eventually managed to install java 9.0.1 with SDKMAN.

With these confessions out of the way I can now state the problem:

I'm on step 3 of the guide, when I type:

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::"
```

I just get:

```
/usr/
```

When I look in my usr/bin file there doesn't even seem to be a java folder?
However there is a java folder in use/local?

Can someone tell me how to complete step 3 "setting the path to Java" with my configuration?

Comment: How did you install java, what does `whereis java` give you?

Comment: I did it using sdkman. When I type in whereis java it gives: java: /usr/local/java /usr/share/java /home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-oracle/bin/java

Comment: I didn't look at the install stuff .. but .. if you type `which java` it will give you the path to the java you are using . java isn't a folder in bin its an executable or possibly a link to the executable probably located in `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: which java gives: /home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java

Comment: I guess in that case I would try `readlink -f /home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java` but I don't know actually what is trying to be accomplished by this command I really am not good with sed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I type in `whereis java` it gives: `java: /usr/local/java /usr/share/java /home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-oracle/bin/java`

The goal of Step 3 is to configure your Java home.
Based on your comment above,
your Java home is `/home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-oracle`,
this is the value to use as `JAVA_HOME` in the `hadoop-env.sh` configuration file. That is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-oracle
```

---

Let me explain a bit more. The instructions ask you to do `readlink -f /usr/bin/java | ...` because the page assumes that you have `/usr/bin/java` symlinked to somewhere. But you don't. Your `java` is in fact in `/usr/local/java`, so in your case the equivalent appropriate step would be:

```
readlink -f /usr/local/java | sed "s:bin/java::"
```

Where, `readlink -f /usr/local/java` will output `/home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-oracle/bin/java`,
and the `sed` command removes the `bin/java` from it,
which leaves you with `/home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java/9.0.1-oracle`.

Comment: My best guess would have be to use $ readlink -f /home/hugh/.sdkman/candidates/java | sed "s:bin/java::"? aS John Orion suggested is this incorrect if so why? You use an alternate methos for setting Java home using the export JAVA_HOME=? Is this method doing exactly the same thing as the original command in step 3 readlink... Sorry for all the questions but I want to learn what is actually happening.

Comment: @Bazman I added more explanation about the reasoning, let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: OK sorry for the stupid noob questions it works in any case thank you so much!

Comment: @Bazman you're welcome, and it was a fair question!