# What is the conventional directory to install Hadoop into?

Tags: software-installation, hadoop

Sooo... Hadoop doesn't have an installer, so can't use apt for it...  Still pretty new at ubuntu stuff... I realize I can install it anywhere, but is there an established convention to be followed for its home directory?

Comment: @K7AAY That question doesn't have any answers with Hadoop's installation directory in it.

Comment: It depends on the download: source (tar, tar.gz) installs go into /opt/ for instance.

Comment: Bottom of step 2 specified /usr/local/hadoop in https://askubuntu.com/questions/986952/installing-hadoop-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop can be installed as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install hadoop --channel=latest/beta
```

This snap installs Hadoop 2.7.3 from the Apache Bigtop 1.2.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

As you can install it in any dir you want. but there's a convention you can use.
In Linux, most user applications are installed in /opt.
If you use Cloudera/Hortonworks distribution. Hadoop and all the stack are installed in /usr/hdp/hdp_version/spark/{bin/etc/examples/...}

So it depends on you.
If you're going to have multiple version for hadoop, and you are going to use them

/opt/hadoop/v2/apache-hadoop-2.x/
/opt/hadoop/v3/apache-hadoop-3.x/

Also. Hadoop configuration can be linked in /etc/ as well.
so you can soft link your actual configuration of hadoop/spark in /etc.

as /etc is used for most of configuration.
ln -s /opt/hadoop/v3/apache-hadoop-3.1/confi /etc/hadoop3

so you can change your configuration /etc/hadoop3/[core-site.xml/hdfs-site.xml] from /etc instead without the need to know where's the location of binaries.